# record multiple browser content (audio and screen) for the same PC

Tags: browser, audio-recording, screen-capture

I record my university lessons.
I use WebEx on Firefox and record full gdi desktop with ffmpeg. Also for audio I record "stereo mix" audio source.

The problem arises when I want to record more than 4 lessons simultaneously, because I have only 4 PCs.

The problem is the common hardware resource "stereo mix". Because it is only one per PC.
For gdi desktop I can split 2-4 firefox windows so there is no problem.

so, the question is: Is there a way to capture content (audio and screen) directly from firefox (any browser) and not from hardware sources like gdi desktop and stereo mix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to ask the presenter to record the session and make it
available via WebEx, although you need the WebEx player to play this format.
See the WebEx article
[Chapter: Recording and Playback](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/collaboration/meeting_center/wbs30/WebEx_BK_MB6269C1_00_meeting-center-frequently-asked-questions/WebEx_BK_MB6269C1_00_meeting-center-frequently-asked-questions_chapter_0101.html).

A solution would be to use the donationware product of
[VB-CABLE Virtual Audio Device](https://vb-audio.com/Cable/).
It creates virtual playback and recording devices, so I think (never tried it)
that you can use more than one browser and connect each one to its own
virtual playback and use in ffmpeg the right virtual recording device.
Some experimenting will be required.

[image]